# Apt Upgrade AND Downgrade all packages to Current Release

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, ppa, pinning

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. While using 12.04, I installed several packages via PPA's. Now that I've upgraded to 14.04, I've discovered that some of the PPA packages from 12.04 are still installed. All of those PPA repositories were removed during upgrade.

I would like to uninstall the PPA package versions of any package that exists in the Ubuntu repositories. For example, I have a SVN version of Audacity that is newer than the version in the Ubuntu repositories, but I want to replace it with the Ubuntu repository version.

I want to do the same thing with all PPA installed packages. I tried pinning this in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/main`

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty
Pin-Priority: 2001

Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty-updates
Pin-Priority: 2002

Package: *
Pin: release a=trusty-security
Pin-Priority: 2003
```

Then

```
apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
```

Unfortunately, it didn't downgrade any packages like I hoped. For example, running `apt-cache show catfish` shows version 1.0.2-2 is available from the Ubuntu repositories, but I still have 1.0.82-1~precise~ppa1 installed.

I want to Downgrade all packages to their current release in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This cannot easily be done in any automated way, especially if you have any PPAs that are giving 404. (which most people do) Also, depending on what packages you have installed, a completely automated downgrade could really screw up your system. Follow these steps to manually find and downgrade packages.

1. Install `Synaptic` if you don't already have it
2. Open `Synaptic`
3. Click on the left side where it reads `Installed (local or obsolete)`
4. Select a package you wish to downgrade on the right side
5. From the menu select: Package -> Force Version
6. Repeat for each package you wish to downgrade

Comment: This is not viable for downgrading ALL packages.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you want to use ppa-purge

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:name-of-ppa/to-be-purged`

`man ppa-purge` indicates that this will "automatically down‐grading all packages in a given PPA back to the ubuntu versions."

Comment: The Ubuntu updater removes all PPAs

Comment: It *disables* all PPAs, which you can re-enable if you change the codename to the appropriate release.

Comment: So the PPAs are still in the file, but disabled?  That will be good to know for future reference.  I suppose that is really not going to help for those packages I installed by downloading debs...

Comment: @saiarcot895 You're correct. The PPAs were disabled.

Comment: @Sepero So essentially you could edit the /etc/apt/sources.list, re-enable the PPAs and then use ppa-purge on them?