# List installed packages that are no longer installable via repository?

Tags: package-management, ppa, dpkg, repository

This question is in reference to [another question that has not been answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491080/apt-upgrade-and-downgrade-all-packages-to-current-release). When I upgraded Ubuntu, all my PPAs were removed (which I'm ok with). Is there a way to list all the packages that no longer have a repository associated with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APT refers to these packages as "[obsolete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286947/obsolete-packages-vs-orphaned-packages)".

Evidently there is no direct way to list these, but you could do:

```
aptitude search '~o'
```

Or alternatively:

```
apt-show-versions | grep 'No available version'
```

Source: [How do I get a list of obsolete packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98223/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-obsolete-packages)

If you want a GUI tool you can do this with Synaptic by using the built-in "[local or obsolete](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/02/07/debian-cleanup-tip-2-get-rid-of-obsolete-packages/)" filter.

Comment: Really thanks for posting the Synaptic solution. For some reason, aptitude is not listing all of the packages without a repository.